# Beta function of the non-linear sigma model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, curvature

In chapter 7.1.1. in [Tong's notes about String Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) could someone sketch how can I show the statements that he makes around eq. 7.5

- That the addition of the counterterm can be absorbed by renormalization the wavefunction and the metric
- How does he conclude from the renormalization
  $$G_{\mu \nu} \rightarrow G_{\mu \nu} + \dfrac{\alpha '}{\epsilon}\mathcal{R}_{\mu\nu} $$
  that the beta function equals
  $$\beta_{\mu\nu}(G) = \alpha ' \mathcal{R}_{\mu \nu} \quad ? $$

Comment: Look up the computation of one-loop beta functions in dimensional regularisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On account of symmetry, 2d σ-models, even though beset with an infinity of counterterms, have those regiment themselves into few geometrical tensors constrained by symmetry; and thus limit themselves to tensors, such as the Ricci, and then underlie the β-function in the conventional manner: it is not zillions of couplings that evolve, it is only the geometry, and, on highly symmetric "pion" manifolds,  by just a scale or two! (For the hypersphere, below, just its radius of curvature--it puffs up to noninteracting flatness, conformal invariance, with energy. cf. Tong 7.1.2)

Both are illustrated in our paper [BCZ 1985](https://www.academia.edu/23761857/TORSION_AND_GEOMETROSTASIS_IN_NONLINEAR_SIGMA_MODELS), and especially in (2.41-2.49) and in Appendix A, meant to answer just these questions. But it is a long story, to which no justice can be done in this short format.

Nevertheless, your second question has a straightforward answer, implicit in Tong's notes, and, of course, section 2 of the paper cited here.

- In *ε = d-2* dimensions, taking the "pion" fields *φ* to be dimensionless, but the *bare* metric to have dimension *ε*, to one loop rewrite your expression as
  $$
  (G_{\mu\nu}/\alpha')^{(0)}=M^\epsilon ( G_{\mu\nu}/\alpha'  -\frac{1}{\epsilon}R^{(1)}_{\mu\nu} ). 
  $$
  But the bare *α'*-full metric must be independent of the RG scale *M*; so operating on this equation by $M \frac{d}{dM}$ at the pole $\epsilon \to 0$ nets
  $$
  0=  M \frac{d}{dM} \frac{G_{\mu\nu}}{\alpha'} - R^{(1)}_{\mu\nu},
  $$
  where the superscript (1) indicates the residue at the pole, and 
  $$
    M \frac{d}{dM} \frac{G_{\mu\nu}}{\alpha'} = R^{(1)}_{\mu\nu}.
  $$

Thus, in our scaled conventions, in a hypersphere [($R_{\mu\nu}=2 G_{\mu\nu}$)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/138789/66086), whose inverse 
radius-squared, *α'*, decreases with scale *M* , asymptotic freedom manifests itself: $d\alpha'/d\ln M =-2\alpha' ^2$. Asymptotically, the sphere flattens to a conformally invariant plane.