# Covariant renormalization of nonlinear sigma model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, renormalization, sigma-models

On page 160-161 in [Tong's notes on string](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/seven.pdf), he calculates one-loop divergent diagram and finds that we need a counter term of $\frac{\alpha'}{3\epsilon}\mathcal{R}_{\mu\nu}\partial Y^{\mu}\partial Y^{\nu}$ (I have put in the coefficient of $\alpha'$). It seems to me that a wavefunction renormalization $Y^{\mu}\to Y^{\mu}+\frac{\alpha'}{6\epsilon}\mathcal{R}^\mu _{ \  \nu} Y^{\nu}$ is sufficient to absorb the counter term. However, Tong says that a renormalization of the metric $G_{\mu\nu}$ by $G_{\mu\nu}\to G_{\mu\nu}+\frac{\alpha'}{\epsilon}\mathcal{R}_{\mu\nu}$ is also needed.

Could some one explain to me why we need both the wavefunction renormalization and metric renormalization here? Does this have to do with the covariance?

Thank you.

Comment: Related [315459](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137162/beta-function-of-the-non-linear-sigma-model/315459#315459).